# dataTable().makeEditable() - how to call a specific action method for Add

Tags: model-view-controller, datatable

In the default implementation of dataTable().makeEditable(), the action method called while clicking on Ok button of the formAddNewRow is AddData(string name, string .....).

How can I call a specific action method such as AddCompany(string name, string .....)?

I have tried using the below code, but it threw an error:
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable({
                sAddURL: "/Admin/AddCOIRole"
              });
        });

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the Controller reference and it is working fine.
sAddURL: "AddCOIRole"